# Deleting seams in the UV Editor

Tags: uv

So I've been following Blender Guru's 2.8 tutorial and I was working on the UV unwrapping. I accidentally placed a seem where I didn't want one and if I press 
'clear seam' nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Provide some simplified blend file with your issue, please. It can be a milion reasons :) Highlighted edge can be accidentally set as "Crease" (Shift+E) to 1 .... ?

Comment: Yes it might something else than seam, also you need to select the edge before the clear seam